# Cable length and voltage drop in offgrid solar installation

Tags: voltage, resistance, solar-cell, cables, mppt

I have connected my Lithium-ion battery pack(11.1v 100ah ) with my Epever MPPT charge controller using 5M length of 8 AWG cable. when i put load which consume around 12A , the charger controller shows 11.4 V as the batter voltage. But when i check the voltage between the battery terminal it shows as 12V.Will it be the problem of cable length?

Comment: Measure the voltage on both sides of the cable with the voltmeter. Don't rely on the voltage displayed by the charge controller (unless you verify that it matches your meter).

Comment: Use AWG 4 or 2.  I might consider insulated 0.5" copper pipe. or move Bat & PMMT controller closer to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWG 8 cable has 2.06Ω/km, so using 5m of it (or 0.005km) would be equivalent to 0.01Ω.

With a 12A current this equates to 0.12V of drop per cable, and 0.24V with both sides of the cable.

However, connectors can also add a significant amount of resistance, make sure that you are using the right connectors and they are terminated properly.

0.6V at 12A would be around 0.05Ω of resistance from the voltage drop, which could be reasonable if the connectors are contributing to the resistance.

If the drop is too much loss consider better cables\connectors and or a higher voltage system (24V) to cut the resistive loss.